# Redundant use of distinct in group by?

Tags: sql, group-by, sas, distinct

I'm reviewing some SQL queries in SAS and I encountered the following query structure:

```
SELECT distinct A, B, Sum(C) FROM Table1 GROUP BY A, B;
```

I would like to know if it's strictly equivalent to:

```
SELECT A, B, Sum(C) FROM Table1 GROUP BY A, B;
```

Or if I'm missing a nuance, in the output or the way the computation is handled

Comment: What do you get for results from both queries?

Comment: Both produce the same result. But the `distinct` is redundant because the A+B-groups are already unique. Maybe the optimizer notices it.

Comment: You are not missing any nuance, the distinct clause is redundant and should be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two queries are equivalent.

Generally,

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c
FROM <something>
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM <something>
GROUP BY a, b, c
```

In your case, `<something>` happens to be a result of `GROUP BY` query, which has distinct columns `A` and `B`. This is enough to ensure that triples `A, B, SUM(C)` are going to be unique as well.